# How to run a server n times on IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, process, coap

I am doing a university project with IntelliJ Idea using the CoAP protocol and I need to emulate the presence of *n* devices (to be precise, I need to emulate the fact that the same sensor is present several times in a given environment).

Since in my project sensors are servers, I turned on "Allow multiple instances" in IntelliJ's Run/Debug Configurations and if I run the same server twice, the first server works fine but in the terminal of the second server I get this:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer - Starting server
[main] INFO org.eclipse.californium.core.network.CoapEndpoint - coap Endpoint at coap://0.0.0.0:5685 is already stopped
[main] ERROR org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer - cannot start server endpoint [0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5685]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.bindInternal(DatagramChannelImpl.java:1194)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.bind(DatagramChannelImpl.java:1164)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.bind(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.californium.elements.UDPConnector.start(UDPConnector.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.californium.core.network.CoapEndpoint.start(CoapEndpoint.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer.start(CoapServer.java:263)
    at it.unimore.fum.iot.server.EnvironmentMonitoringCoapProcess.main(EnvironmentMonitoringCoapProcess.java:54)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: None of the server endpoints could be started
    at org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer.start(CoapServer.java:271)
    at it.unimore.fum.iot.server.EnvironmentMonitoringCoapProcess.main(EnvironmentMonitoringCoapProcess.java:54)
```

I know the address is already in use, as the first server is already using it.
But then how can I emulate the *n* devices?

*Note: with n devices, I mean at least 3/4 devices, in order to show the correct functioning of the developed system.*

Comment: The purpose of that option is to allow running the same "class" multiple times. You have to handle the logic, like in this case, to make that happen. IntelliJ will not handle it by itself. I suggest you creating a test class that creates several threads, each one with a different port, or, having a "Session" class that is responsible to create a new port that is not in use, or use Unit/Integration tests for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you really want to do. Maybe it's more mixing up terms as devices, clients, and servers. Anyway, you may start a CoapServer using "CoapServer(final int... ports)" in order to use different ports. Or provide more information and create a issue in https://github.com/eclipse/californium/issues/new/choose